fantasy manga about op demon lord mc goes to human town through the gate
i remember i read fantasy manga about op demon lord mc goes to human town then that human town got attacked by some syndicate to open demon world gate but its turn out all demon that come out throught the gate kneel to the MC and last chapter i read the mc fought giant demon girl

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?
